# Do not require subroutes to use route group parameter

Tags: php, laravel

Lets say I have the following code:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{tenant_domain}.myapp.com', 'middleware' => 'tenant'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // send to dashboard/login based on auth
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
        // login routes
        Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

        // password reset routes
        Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
        Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
        Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    });
});
```

Now, the `tenant` middleware utilizes the `tenant_domain`. However, I want to make it so that none of the subroutes require `tenant_domain` as a parameter in their controllers.

How do I do this?

Comment: That's not what I want. I want the `tenant_domain` to be required for the route group, but I do not want to have every route in the group require this parameter as it is being utilized in the middleware only. I've tried using `forgetParamater` in the `tenant` middleware and that didn't work.

Comment: You are sure that this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/remove-subdomain-parameter-in-controllers didn't work ?

Comment: I put `$request->route()->forgetParameter('tenant_domain');` in the middleware handler and that did not fix it.